# Can't deploy nodejs Cloud Function on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I followed this guide: [medium](https://alonge.medium.com/how-to-setup-slack-integration-for-google-cloud-build-using-cloud-functions-e357b580c7a1) on how to deploy slack notification on gcp for Cloud Build but when I deploy I got this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.

Any help?

Comment: For a more detailed error message, look into your function's [build logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building#accessing_your_build_image_logs), as well as your function's [runtime logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_runtime_logs). If can't still figure out the problem, edit your question and add the information those logs show you.

Comment: Did you check the nodejs version compliance?

Comment: The error could be caused by various reasons such as faulty global scope code logic or incompatible dependency mismatches. check with this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) which will specify the  dependencies in `Node.js`.